# how is my declared id an array?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've implemented an edit-form, so once I edit the form and submit, it's supposed to query the database and change the values based on the `caseid`, however, I'm getting an error when making a query to `$caseid`, it gives me the following error:

> conversion from array to string.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the core snippets that are the source of the problem:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] != "*/*" and isset($_REQUEST['executa']) and $_REQUEST['executa'] != "")
{
    $msg = edit_case($_REQUEST, $dbi,$Session_Userid, $pixel_header_ary, $caseid);
    if ($msg == ""){
        switch($_REQUEST['executa'])
        {
        case 'view':
            $msg = "Edited a request successfully.";
            break;

            case 'list':
            $url = "location:main.php";
            header($url);
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo $msg;
    }
} ?>
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="executa" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="caseid" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['request_id'];?>" />
    <div id="detalle_info">
        <div class="bloque_info"><h1><br>Case Info.</h1></div>
        <table id="case_info" class="tabla_info_a" summary="">
            <?php
                print_case_info($caseModel);
            ?>
        </table>

    </div>
```

And

```
function edit_case($req,$dbi,$suid, $pixel_header_ary, $caseid)
{
    $name = $_REQUEST['case_name'];
    $silver = $_REQUEST['sil_ver'];
    $lot = $_REQUEST['lot'];
    $wafer = $_REQUEST['wafer'];
    $setver = $_REQUEST['set_ver'];
    //$sql = "UPDATE `test`.`case` SET case_name = '$name' where case_id = '85'";
    $sql = "UPDATE `test`.`case` SET case_name = '$name' where case_id = $caseid";
    $dbi->query($sql);
```

The actual code is too long so I hope it's clear enough with these snippets..

The problem is the `$caseid` being an array apparently.

Edit:  Problem is still happening.  I think the biggest reason I'm confused is because I don't even know how it got to be an array...I'm just requesting an id so shouldn't it just be a string?

Comment: and where is $caseid declared/defined in your code?

Comment: what does `var_dump($caseid)` tell you if you output it just before your $dbi->query? (Better yet, if you use a debug tool, set a breakpoint at that line and inspect $caseid

Comment: What does `print_r($_REQUEST['request_id']);` and `print_r($caseid);` return to you ?

Comment: @koala_dev the hidden field.

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST['request_id']); returns "1".  print_r($caseid); returns "notfound1".

Comment: vardump doesnt appear to give me anything

Comment: This may be a stupid comment, but I didn't know that you could use strings in switch statements. Have you thought of trying to use integers? --Edit: Nevermind. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php My argument is invalid.

Comment: @user2562568 your query seems wrong `echo $sql;` gives you what ? you said above `$caseid` gives you `notfound1` so you're changing it somewhere in-between the submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your $caseid variable, and see what's up with it:

```
print_r($caseid);
```

If it turns out that it is actually an array, you might need to specify the key:

```
$caseid[0]
```

Comment: how would I be able to specify it?  I've tried setting $caseid to $caseid[0] but I'm getting "undefined offset: 0"

Comment: Try this: `echo "<pre>";
    print_r($caseid); 
    echo "</pre><br>";`

Are you sure that you want $caseid and not $_POST['caseid']? I can't see the code that puts the form variable into $caseid

Comment: What does `echo gettype($caseid);` return?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  I define $caseid like 
`$caseid = (isset($_REQUEST['request_id'])? $_REQUEST['request_id'] : null);` , where it is returning null.  If I change null to a string, it will return a string.  So that means $caseid is never being set.  Although now I'm confused how I can get it to properly request then haha.  I'm currently working on it and will post any updates.

Comment: You don't have a form element named "request_id" in the code above. What you want is $_POST['caseid'] (or $_GET['caseid'], depending on what this form's action is).

Comment: solved.  I declared it as `$caseid = $_SESSION('caseid');`  Thanks for the help!